# how to reduce button height to fit parent layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to reduce the height of a button to fit into the height of it's parent layout? I do not want to specify any specific dimension value.

I have a simple layout that has a `TextView` and a `Button` inside a `RelativeLayout`. But the height of this layout is too big because it tries to fit the default height of the button.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reminder"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_addremainder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change button layout_height to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent Layout is set to wrap_content, therefore button is set to wrap_content.

Instead change your parent layout (RelativeLayout) to have a *specific height* or *match_parent*. That way the button will fit the parent instead the parent fitting the button.

**Simply put:** you need some element to have a specific height, so other elements can scale accordingly.

If that's not what you want perhaps all what you need to do is to remove the minHeight of the button:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: i have specified the parent layout's layout_height="20dp". This helps, but now the button is clipped vertically. It is the same behaviour when i set `android:minHeight="0dp"` for the button as well. I was hoping to reduce the height of the button so that the "+" is visible, instead of having it clipped

Comment: @faizal also try removing the padding `android:padding="0dp"`